# Angular 5 filter multiple values from json array seperated by comma

Tags: angular

## Angular 5 filter multiple value from json array seperated  by comma:

I'm using Angular 5  in my project. I'm able to filter single value from search box but what I want to achieve is to filter multiple values from search box seperated by comma.
Any help would be appreciated.

## Filter -

```js
export class FilterPersonPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], value: string, label:string): any[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!value) return  items;
        if (value == '' || value == null) return [];
        //value = value.split(',');
        var filterVal = value.split(",");
    
        return items.filter(e => e[label].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterVal) > -1);
    }
```

## html -

```html
<div class="form-group nav nav-pills flex-column " id="div-testFilter">
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 pull-right span3" id="form-testFilter">
        <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="text" id="input-testFilter"
               class="form-control mr-sm-2"  type="text" placeholder="filter Person"
               aria-label="Search"  >
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of person|filterPerson:searchText: 'name' ; let i = index" >
            <td>{{p.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: that is my filter pipe:

Comment: export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: any[], val: string, label:string): any[] {
    if (!input) return [];
    if (!val) return  items;
    if (val == '' || val == null) return [];
    //val = value.split(',');
    var filterVal = value.split(",");
          return input.filter(e => e[label].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterVal) > -1);

  }

Comment: @wkhan : Better add that code to your Q, not as a comment.